# Riverpod - ref.onDispose called when object is created, and not when disposed

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have this ViewModel and a [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) provider for it:

```
final signInViewModelProvider = Provider.autoDispose<SignInViewModel>((ref) {
  final vm = SignInViewModel();

  ref.onDispose(() {
    vm.cleanUp();
  });

  return vm;
});

class SignInViewModel extends VpViewModelNew {
  FormGroup get form => _form;
  String get emailKey => _emailKey;
  String get passwordKey => _passwordKey;

  final String _emailKey = UserSignInFieldKeys.email;
  final String _passwordKey = UserSignInFieldKeys.password;

  final FormGroup _form = FormGroup({
    UserSignInFieldKeys.email:
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
    UserSignInFieldKeys.password:
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required])
  });

  void cleanUp() {
    print('cleaning up');
  }

  void onSubmitPressed(BuildContext context) {
    // _saveRegistrationLocallyUseCase.invoke(
    // form.control(_self.emailKey).value as String ?? '',
    // form.control(_self.passwordKey).value as String ?? '');
  }
}

abstract class VpViewModelNew {
  VpViewModelNew() {
    if (onCreate != null) {
      onCreate();
      print('creating');
    }
  }

  void onCreate() {}
}
```

When I navigate to the page that has the `signInViewModelProvider`, it prints to the console:

```
flutter: signInPage building
flutter: creating
flutter: cleaning up
```

Then popping the page from the stack with `Navigator.pop()` prints nothing.

Then navigating to the page again prints the same 3 lines in the same order.

I expected `onDispose` to be called after `Navigator.pop()`, and not when navigating to the page that reads the provider. Why is `onDispose` being called directly after creation, and not when using `Navigator.pop()` (when I expected the provider to be disposed of since no other views reference it)?

Edit: I access the provider with `final viewModel = context.read<SignInViewModel>(signInViewModelProvider);`

Comment: And how exactly is the provider being read in the page?

Comment: @EdwynZN just added to the bottom of the question, thank you

Comment: Use a consumer or consumerWidget, context.read doesn't keep the provider alive, just read it once and that's it, consumer keep it listening until the widget is disposed (Navigator.pop)

Comment: @EdwynZN Thank you. Will do tonight. Just wondering, I don't need to listen since I don't need to rebuild the page on change. Is consumer less performant for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need to listen since I don't need to rebuild the page on
> change. Is consumer less performant for this?

No, the performance is meaningless, even if it's listening it's not really affecting the performance because as a Provider there is no way to notify (which is not the case with a state notifier or change notifier)

Also if you don't care to listen after the value has been read The auto dispose understand no one is watching it and it disposes, it's better to use context.read when using tap or gestures that modify something

Answer (score 0):

(I realize this is late to the party but maybe it'll help somebody)

The [Riverpod docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-refread-to-obtain-the-state-of-a-provider) come out pretty strongly against using `read` for the reason you said, i.e. performance/rebuilding concerns.

Basically you should *always* use `watch` except:

- If you want your custom callback function called when it updates (use `listen`)
- If the actual reading is happening asynchronously or in response to user action (like in an `onPressed`): this is the only time to use `read`.

If you're having issues with your widgets rebuilding too often, [Riverpod has some ways to deal with that that don't involve using `read`.](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-select-to-filter-rebuilds)